# Event listener of multiple events

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

This is a best-practices question.

Suppose I have a class, A, with two buttons inside, buttonOne and buttonTwo.
Another class, B, wishes to listen to the click event of both buttons, but doesn't need to hold an actual reference to said buttons (or knows how to get ahold of A).

What will be the best way to distinguish between the two buttons inside the event handler in B?

```
private void button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Who is the sender? buttonOne? buttonTwo?
}
```

Is there any way other than relying on the name/text of the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your choices are:

- Use different event handlers.
- Keep references to the buttons.  You may prefer `WeakReference`s if it is possible for `B` to outlive the UI.
- Create a subclass of `Button` that exposes the difference between them through some property or method.
- Distinguish the buttons using some existing property of `Button`.  The preferred property for this purpose should be `Tag`, not `Name` or `Text`.

Comment: Thanks, I think you got it all covered.